Simplify the inequality to show that k is limited
In one part of a mathematical proof, I needed to show that k is limited. I logarithmized the inequality and ultimately I got this
\begin{align*}
& \frac{\ln(S) - \ln(c(\alpha)) + k!n\cdot\ln(10)}{k!\cdot\ln(10)} - 1 \geq k
\end{align*}
Here, S is the finite sum of geometric series and $c(\alpha)$ is a constant.
I was told that now all I need to do is to divide the denominator and the numerator on the left side by k!
I get
\begin{align*}
\frac{{\left(\ln(S) - \ln(c(a))\right)/k!}}{{\ln(10)}} + n - 1 \geq k
\end{align*}
But I still don't fully see how this shows that k is limited. Is it because as k! increases, the $\frac{{\left(\ln(S) - \ln(c(a))\right)/k!}}{{\ln(10)}}$ tends to zero, leaving us with a simple n - 1?

Yes, that is the reason why $k$ cannot assume arbitrarily large values
